# How can I embed a custom streetview in android app?

Tags: android, mapactivity, google-street-view

I know this is the way to start a street view Intent:

```
String uriString = "google.streetview:cbll=44.640381,-63.575911&cbp=1,90,,0,1.0"; 
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString); 
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

What I want to do is to listen the GeoPoint (MapView.getMapCenter()) of the street view.

e.g. Initially user open streetview at GeoPoint A. User can tap to move along the 
street.

I want to record all footprints (GeoPoints) of the user. Any idea?

Regards,
Ken

Answer (score 1):

Android does not currently support streetview in the current Maps API.

What you are doing is starting a new intent for the Maps application, leaving your application.

You will need to find another solution using MapView and see if you can find a library that gives you the streetviews.

Comment: Ok. It seems that only embed web street view + javascript in android webview is the only solution.

Comment: There's your answer then.  As a new user, remember to upvote and/or check an answer as correct if it answers your question.  Glad you found a solution. :)